# Why are additional style files pulled in?

Tags: google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I am troubleshooting a small Html file which has just one style sheet referenced. This is https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.

Chrome Developer Tools `Network` tab shows that this is the only css file that is downloaded.

However, when inspecting an element in Chrome Developer Tools, there are no styles in boostrap.min.css. Instead, there are references to styles that are in files such as `_navbar.scss`. They are shown with line numbers, and if I click such a link, it opens up https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/_navbar.scss in the `Sources` tab.

I am now confused. How does this `_navbar.scss` file get involved? Why are there no styles found in bootstrap.min.css?

This is what it looks like when inspecting elements:

[image]

Am I using Chrome Developer Tools wrongly?

Comment: You're seeing sourcemaps.

Comment: These files aren't loaded, they just reference where the rules were before compiling the Sass to CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the source code from which was collected `bootstrap.min.css`. 
The bootstrap 4 source files are written in sass and looking like this:

[image]

This is available thanks to the source maps that are downloaded and attached to the browser when you open the developer tools. Until then the browser is not aware of the sourceMap. Don't worry everything works as it should.